# Using the Rblapi package to pull data

Tags: r, xts, bloomberg, rblpapi

I have a list of ISINs which is my only source of information. In Excel I can catch the Bloomber ticker which is needed in many cases because it specifies the code of the exchange on which the asset is traded. To do so I only have to add "... Equity isin" in a BDP()-Formula  where "..." is a placeholder for the ISIN.
So with the new Rblpapi package (which is by the way a fantastic tool!) I can try to do the same:

Here is a list of random ISINs

```
isins = c("LU0942970442", "LU0997545750"  ,"CH0019597530" , "CH0017142719"  , "CH0131872431", "VGG0475N1087", "US46429B6974", 
"LU0911032141"  , "DE000A1JCWS9")
```

adding "equity" and calling "TICKER_AND_EXCH_CODE" within the bdp formula

```
require(Rblpapi)
blpConnect()    

portfolio_ticker = bdp(paste(c(isins),"equity"), "TICKER_AND_EXCH_CODE")
```

however leaves some Tickers unspecified.

```
> portfolio_ticker
                    TICKER_AND_EXCH_CODE
LU0942970442 equity              XBAC SW
LU0997545750 equity           AXESZHD LX
CH0019597530 equity                     
CH0017142719 equity                     
CH0131872431 equity                     
VGG0475N1087 equity           ARIASII VI
US46429B6974 equity                     
LU0911032141 equity           FCEUSMI LX
DE000A1JCWS9 equity           CHOMCAR GR
```

My question is: Is this a thinking-error on my side or is this a bug in the package?

**EDIT:** As an example how it looks on my side in Excel, here is the corresponding picture.

[image]

Comment: probably because there is more than one ticker mapping to those isins. For example, CH0019597530 maps to 4 different tickers: AMGSSCHFEU, AMGSSCHFEO, AMGS    SW, AMGSSCH SW

Comment: And it doesn't work in Excel either

Comment: Just added a screen shot from the Excel sheet. It does work in there though...

Comment: My bad, I was trying with "LU0942970442 equity", not "LU0942970442 ISIN". See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rblpapi uses the C API - to query isins you need to format them like this:

```
/isin/THE_ISIN_HERE
```

So in your example, this should work:

```
bdp("/isin/LU0942970442", "TICKER_AND_EXCH_CODE")
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Let me add to this absolute stellar finding this different option for those using ID059 (also known as BUID). This will work:
`bdp(paste("/BUID/", unique(thisList$ID059)),  "ID_ISIN")`